# In my Supabase project, user information stored in auth doesn't seem to be automatically added to the profiles table in real-time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, supabase

``In my Supabase project, user information stored in auth doesn't seem to be automatically added to the profiles table in real-time. I'm curious about how to configure this in a Supabase project. Could you please provide guidance on what settings are required?

```
// ... (코드 상단 생략)
register.tsx

const joinUsHandler = async (e: FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!email || !password || !name || !confirmPassword) {
    setError("모든 칸을 입력하세요.");
    return;
  }
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    setError("비밀번호가 일치하지 않습니다.");
    return;
  }
  try {
    setLoading(true);

    const signUpResult: any = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email,
      password,
    });

    if (signUpResult.error) {
      console.error(signUpResult.error);
      if (signUpResult.error.message.includes("Email rate limit exceeded")) {
        alert("이메일 발송 제한이 초과되었습니다. 나중에 다시 시도해주세요.");
      }
      return;
    }
    const { user } = signUpResult.data;

    if (user) {
      console.log("User registered:", user);
      await supabase.from("profiles").upsert([
        {
          user_id: user.id,
          username: name,
        },
      ]);
      setError("");
      setSuccessRegister(true);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

// ... (코드 하단 생략)
```

login.tsx

```
// ... (코드 상단 생략)

const loginHandler = async (e: FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const { data, error } = await (
      supabase.auth as SupabaseClient["auth"]
    ).signInWithPassword({
      email,
      password,
    });
    if (error) {
      console.error((error as any).message);
      alert("로그인 정보를 다시 확인해주세요");
      return;
    }
    
    // ...

    // zustand
    setFullName(data.user.user_metadata.full_name);

    // 토큰 저장 - 일반 로그인
    if (data.user) {
      const session = await supabase.auth.getSession();
      // ...

      const accessToken = session?.data?.session?.access_token;
      if (accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
        // ...

        // zustand
        setAccessToken(accessToken);

        alert("로그인에 성공했습니다. 메인페이지로 이동합니다.");
        navigate("/");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error((error as any).message);
  }
};

// ... (코드 하단 생략)
```

I think my code is not wrong. but I think I have to do some settings in my supabse project.`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make a trigger in the supabase database, in the:

> SQL Editor > Quickstarts > User Management Starter option

[image]

This guide helps you to automate the process of inserting the profile in the profiles table.